# PhyML installation using make return unknown error

Tags: gcc, installation, makefile

I am trying to install the program Phyml. I am following the instruction but when I compile make I get the following error that I cannot understand.

```
sudo make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/lib/partitionfinder-master/programs/phyml_source'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/lib/partitionfinder-master/programs/phyml_source/src'


:: Building [phyml]. Version 20150123 ::


gcc  -I. -I..     -ansi -pedantic -Wall -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -funroll-loops -arch i386 -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -MT main.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/main.Tpo -c -o main.o main.c
gcc: error: i386: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-arch’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mmacosx-version-min=10.4’
make[2]: *** [main.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/lib/partitionfinder-master/programs/phyml_source/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/lib/partitionfinder-master/programs/phyml_source'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any idea how I could address this problem?

Comment: You generally don't need `sudo` for `make` (and shouldn't use it for that either). The problems here are that those two options are OS X specific and you aren't on an OS X machine. You need to see if you can control the target/host the build expects in some way or manually override those arguments.

Comment: What `./configure` command did you use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by deleting the files and downloading a new version of the program Phyml. 
I then installed it in the canonical way, and I copied the executable in the sub-folder `/usr/local/lib/partitionfinder-master/programs/`.